# What prevents someone from subverting qualified exports by pretending to be a module they are not?

Tags: java, java-module, java-security

Given:

```
module A
{
  exports fuzzy.bunny to B;
}
```

What prevents a malicious player from pretending to be module `B` in order to gain access to module `A`'s secrets?

I know that Java has some sort of signing mechanism in `META-INF` that allows each module to ensure that its own class files have not been modified, but what mechanism ensures that one module can trust another module's class files?

Comment: I think the question is what if `C` renames itself to `B`, would I be able to restrict access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not precisely be the answer you are looking for, but a part of [JMOD file creation using **`jmod`** tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jmod.htm#JSWOR-GUID-0A0BDFF6-BE34-461B-86EF-AAC9A555E2AE) explains it briefly :

```
--hash-modules
```

> With the `--hash-modules` option or the `jmod hash` command, you can, in
>   each module's descriptor, record *hashes* of the content of the modules
>   that are allowed to depend upon it, thus "tying" together these
>   modules. This let’s you to *allow a package to be exported to one or
>   more specifically-named modules and to no others through qualified
>   exports*. The runtime verifies if the recorded hash of a module matches
>   the one resolved at run time; if not, the runtime returns an error.

further from the same documentation

> These hashes are recorded in the JMOD archive file being created, or a
>   JMOD archive or modular JAR on the module path specified by the `jmod hash` command.

***Useful***: There is a hashing example in the link shared above as well which depicts a use case to which your question quite relates.